# php <?php stored in a variable to build a form not

Tags: php

Really simple question, yet I can't seem to find an answer.

I'm building a form into a variable $form to display depending on certain criteria.

```
$form .= '<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> "method="post">';
```

However, this particular line is making "method="post"> in my form. I've tried escaping all "" and still cant fix it. What am I missing?

Comment: what are you trying to do and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
$form .= '<form action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . ' "method="post">';
```

When you're inside a php block you shouldn't try and use `<?php ?>` also as you're just creating a string you don't need to echo out another string inside it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$form .= '<form action="'. htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])'."method="post">';
```

Try this please!, As I see you are already coding php. A variable can`t content an echo.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$form .= '<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> "method="post">';
```

to

```
$form .= '<form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
```

Always check the html source your program generates in your browser when you have problems.

You're already in php mode so shouldn't need to use tags.
Also you want your generated html code to look like this:

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post">
```

Notice where you have spaces and such.